# Slide out ListView from side like in new GMail App

Tags: android, android-listview

In the new GMail app you can slide out the list of folders from the left side.

I'd like to learn how this is done, and know if this is a feature of the Android SDK or did Google implement a custom effect to make this happen.

I've read about SliderDrawer and Fragments, but nothing seems similar to what they do.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the new [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) UI pattern. They have [instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) on how to set it up in your app.

Comment: This is great! Thanks, I wasn't expecting it to be such a nicely documented feature. I was looking in wrong places.

Answer (score 2):

Use   [NavigationDrawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

and done with framelayout